# How to correctly write a function that is a greeting?

Tags: javascript, function

I am  creating a function that returns a personalized greeting but when I go to return the function it says I pass 1 out of 4 test

Here is the code:

```
function greeting('Omari'){
  console.log('Hello')
}
 greeting();
```

Comment: Can you show us the tests as well?

Answer (score 0):

Make your code ask for a name with `prompt()`. Then write a function that takes a parameter `name` and return a greeting:

```js
 

function greeting(name) {
return "Hello, " + name + "!";
}

var myName = prompt("What's your name?");
alert(greeting(myName));
```